# How to show a loading graphic while a file is getting uploaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

The file should be uploaded in the background via Ajax or Iframes. I should be able to detect via javascript when the upload has completed, so I can hide the loading graphic and redirect the user to a new URL. Using Jquery is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out **[jQuery Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/)**

**EDIT:** There's also a similar question: [how-to-upload-file-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-to-upload-file-jquery) - you could display the graphic after the upload button has been clicked and hide in the success/onerror function callback.

Comment: I'm having troubles getting Uploadify to work with CodeIgniter. It always gives me an I/O error. Do you know how to make it work with Codeigniter?

Comment: I have't used it with CodeIgniter, but there are some posts on that: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/109751/#554977

Answer (score 0):

The jquery [Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is capiable of doing Ajax upload (using an iframe i believe).  It won't help you out directly with showing/hiding an loading image, but it has the appropriate events so you know when the upload starts and finishes.